# Which image format is cost effective in terms of network operation for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, image, format

I want to display a thumbnail image in a `cell` of `tableViewController`, this thumbnail image is located at some remote place (URL of address is in XML file) so which format of image is cost effective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mostly the same as on the Web, really. For graphics, PNG is generally more efficient; for photos, you'll want to pick JPEG.

I'm not sure whether the iPhone supports JPEG 2000 (OS X does), so that may be a more efficient options for photos.

Also consider tools such as `optipng` and `jpegtran` to shed some additional kilobytes off your image data.

Answer (score 3):

Create a sample thumbnail, convert it to PNG, GIF and JPEG, and see which is smaller.

Sometimes measuring is easier than guessing.

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation for images in a `UITableView` is ***PNG***, this has the best rendering performance.

Comment: This probably the best answer of the bunch. PNGs are highly recommended by Apple for performance and picking the right image format could have dramatic performance on table responsiveness.